# Facebook share not going to newsfeed

Tags: facebook, share, timeline, feed

I am developing a site with multiple subdomains/urls, e.g.

```
www.example.com
test.example.com
```

When I try to share to Facebook using

```
www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.example.com
```

Everything works fine as expected, it goes to my newsfeed (my friend's feed) as well as my timeline.

But when I try to share to Facebook as:

```
www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://test.example.com
```

The share only goes to my timeline and NOT to my newsfeed and my friends cannot see it.

The site is relatively new. I wonder if Facebook needs to approve the site and all its sub-domains/URLs before it would put it on the newsfeed?

Comment: Please add the code of how you shared it exactly

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is the exact code. I have tried FB.Ui as well as just putting the share URL  in browser.

Comment: One more piece of information, the content for www.example.com and test.example.com is very difference. www.example.com is my corporate site. test.example.com is my client's portal

Comment: Items on the newsfeed are shown based on a ranking. If a post has a higher rank it is more likely to be shown. Not everything you publish goes to a friend's newsfeed.
This looks like expected behavior.